# Como alterar datas do formato americano y/m/d para d/m/y em um dataframe em R?

Tags: r

Tenho um dataframe em que as datas estão no formato americano e gostaria de saber como faço para transformar esta coluna para o formato brasileiro dia-mês-ano.

Tentei o pacote `lubridate` e a função `dmy`, mas por algum motivo não está executando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

A função `dmy` converte apenas datas no formato dia/mês/ano. Perceba que a coluna Date possui, além da data, um horário. Utilize a função `dmy_hms`, no qual `hms` significa hora, minuto e segundo, respectivamente.

Comment: Tudo bem Marcos,

Comment: Para resolver este problema eu convertir esta coluna para data usando: dados$Date <- as.Date(dados$Date)  *** formato original <dttm>*** e depois apliquei a função dmy do pacote lubridade e não deu certo, mas confesso que não tenho certeza que os argumentos estão corretos. Baseados nestas informações qual o script que você usaria para alterar esta coluna para o formato dia-mês-ano?

Comment: @Rogério Não use `as.Date`, faça diretamente `dados$Date <- mdy_hms(etc)`. E repare que há funções `dmy_hms`, com dia primeiro e `mdy_hms` com mês primeiro. No seu caso é **mês** primeiro.